# Adding custom field to a backend form

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

I am working on a symfony 1.4 project and am trying to add a custom field in a backend form. At the moment, my module has a batch history with editing and deleting options for each row and a form that allows the user to filter through it. I would like to add a custom creation form and I am struggling to do that.

- Going on the `/*model_name*/new/` page does show me a form: this is the form I would like to make changes to.
- I would like to display a dropdown list of elements from another table (and model) on this page. How can I do that knowing that the current module's `widgetSchema` doesn't have that relation?
- Should I edit **generator.yml**? When I try adding a `title:` to `new:` , it doesn't seem to affect the `/new/` page (even after cache:clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you create that relation in your schema.yml. Your generated form will be able to render the widget you want.

Otherwise, what you need to do is edit the *model_name*Form class by adding the widget and validator you want (sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice and sfValidatorDoctrineChoice in your case)

The generator.yml uses the form *model_name*Form class by default, but I suggest you copy this class in a lib folder you create in your module, and edit this one instead. Then, you edit your generator.yml to use this new form, [this is how you do it](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/12?orm=Doctrine#chapter_12_sub_class)

Also, make sure there is not much rows in the table of your relation. Else, symfony will try to generate a html select tag with a lot of options and you will need to kill your php and even webserver processes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose the second solution by adding a widget & validator for the second model, aswell as setting up an alternative form in the backend part, as you suggested. However, the dropdown list now displays IDs I am not familiar with. They don't correspond to the ones from my table.

I used `'network_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getModelName('Network'), 'add_empty' => false))` in `setWidgets()` and `'network_id' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getModelName('Network')))` in `setValidators()`. What would be the cause?

Comment: At first glance, I think you should not use the $this->getModelName() method as it only returns the model name of the current sfFormObject. Just pass the model name 'Network' as a string.

Comment: Thank you, `'model' => 'Network'` seems to work! However I am still not sure I understand how network names appear in the dropdown list and not something else, like their IDs ?

Comment: By default, it displays the value returned by the __toString() method of the model you ask. [See here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice)
But you can change the method used by passing another method name in the 'method' option of the sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice.
Do not hesitate to look through the widget classes phpdoc if you have a good IDE

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to edit **generator.yml**, but in the *form* line:

```
# apps/backend/modules/whatever/config/generator.yml
config:
  ...
  form:
    display:
      Whatever...
```

Here you have some examples. Taken from the official documentation:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/12?orm=Doctrine#chapter_12_form_views_configuration

This way, the form that the generator uses will be the one you specify. And maybe you don't need to modify something else.